# Transactional Emails {Error in template processing}

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, transactional-mail

We have a problem with our transactional emails in Magento they are including {Error in template processing} in the header and the footer. I think this was caused since we updated Magento from **1.7** to **1.9.2.4**. Example below:

> {Error in template processing}

Dear Customer,

(Order information goes here)

> {Error in template processing}

I have seen this question asked on other forums but none of them seem to provide a clear answer. I have moved the files email-inline.css and email-non-inline.css to /skin/frontend/(Theme_name)/default/css but this has not done anything.

Would be grateful if someone could shed some light on this.